# Saving Date Components in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I have troubles saving a time. Let me show you a screenshot, it will make clear what I'm trying to achieve here.

[image: Screenshot]

I am saving a day as an `Int` and from that I create a new Date, that is handled. Only thing what is missing is adding time to that date. How can I save AM or PM in a date?

Also, will that affect users who use 24-hour time in their iPhones? If I save 9 PM will their system know that I really mean 21 hrs for them?

Okay, I forgot about the code, here it is:
This is a piece of code where I am scheduling a notification

```
let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent

        guard let lastPeriod = RealmManager.sharedInstance.queryLastPeriod(), let predictionDate = lastPeriod.predictionDate else {
            return
        }

        let day = predictionDate.day - DefaultsManager.getNotificationDays()

        let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, year: predictionDate.year, month: predictionDate.month, day: day, hour: time, minute: 0)
```

As you can see that `hour` part of `newComponents` is tricky. I only need to provide is it 9AM, 12AM or 9PM. How do I do that? (btw. `time` is just an `Int` I'm manually inputting for testing)

Comment: What do you mean by "saving"? You store it in the user defaults?
Show us a piece of code so we can help you

Comment: A `Date` is a date. A fixed point in time, regardless of the timezone or whether it is displayed as a 24 hour clock or with AM PM indicators.

Comment: I added my code! Thanks for reminding me...

Comment: There's no AM or PM in a date itself. 21:00 is the time, not "9PM" - wether you *display* 21:00 as "21h" or as "9PM" is only a matter of *display*.

Comment: So if I hardcode 21 it will work with phones that have 12-hour preference?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you use 24h-style hours (what else?).

```
let dc = DateComponents(year: 2016, month: 01, day: 11, hour: 14, minute: 20)
let d = Calendar.current.date(from: dc)
//> d: Date? = 2016-01-11 13:20:00 UTC
```

This is correct since my current timezone is CET (UTC+1).

You can use `DateFormatter` to print dates in different formats. For example:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
df.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
df.string(from: d!)
//> R4: String = "11/01/16 14:20"
```

Back to my timezone!

`DateFormatter` also has a method `date(from: String)` which you can use to parse dates:

```
df.date(from: "11/01/16 14:20")
//> R5: Date? = 2016-01-11 13:20:00 UTC
```

You will have to use settings of `Calendar` and/or `DateFormatter` to get 12h-style output. On the input site, you can just map `xxAM` to `Int("xx")!` and `xxPM` to `12 + Int("xx")!`.